# Is it possible to restrict images from loading using selenium web-driver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, excel

I'm using excel selenium to scrape some information from pages with lots of images. Is it possible to make the browser don't load the images of the page? So it  could be more faster.

Comment: Hi Thalles, and welcome to SQA Stack Exchange. On this site, you need to demonstrate that you have tried to solve the problem yourself before asking for help; can you edit your question to describe what investigations you have made, and what you have found out about webdriver's control of what the browser loads?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is possible for an example see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157994/do-not-want-images-to-load-and-css-to-render-on-firefox-in-selenium-webdriver-te

I am wondering if Selenium is the right [crawler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler) to get text from a website.
If you need to crawl dynamic sites than a headless browser like PhantomJS will be much faster: https://www.sitepoint.com/web-crawling-node-phantomjs-horseman/

If the site is static plain http crawlers will be even faster.